# Can I download AOSP and compile the Android OS on a MacBook or other macOS device?

Tags: android, android-source

My computer is a MacBook, and I want to download and compile Android. However, there is something saying on the Internet that AOSP can be downloaded directly on Mac, but it may pollute the system.

So, can I download and compile Android on my MacBook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Not anymore.

macOS used to be a supported platform for building AOSP; however, as of June 21, 2021, [support has been removed](https://source.android.com/setup/build/initializing).

So, if you're building a version of AOSP from before then, it should work, but no new versions (including the current one) will support that.

Answer (score 0):

You can still build Android 12 on macOS (even on Apple Silicon Macs). However, for some unknown reason Google removed macOS support in the fresh Android 13.